# How to create a link in LWC which will open another LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using NavigationMixin. But it will help to open record/list. I want similar link to open another LWC.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__objectPage',
                attributes: {
                    objectApiName: 'Account',
                    actionName: 'list'
                },
                state: {
                    filterName: 'Recent'
                },
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

[There](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type) is option to add link to standard__component. It only supports aura.
So for now you need to embed your LWC component into aura component with `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface implemented. 
Something like that:

```
<!-- c:MyLightningComponent -->
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable">
  <aura:attribute name="counter" type="Integer"/>

  <c:lwcComponent/>
</aura:component>
```

So your navigation will be like

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__component',
    attributes: {
        componentName: 'c__MyLightningComponent'
    },
    state: {
        c__counter: '5'
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot @ytiq